# Create a set of objects when their type is set by ini file (Python)

Tags: python, class, dynamic

I'm working on a smart home project. I've got a bunch of pieces, such as a handful of XBee readios, leds, GPS-synched clocks, water counters etc. I tried to use OOP approach, so I created many classes and subclasses. Now all you have to do in code is to define hardware, connect it by class-built-in function to a parent and enjoy.
To get an idea:

```
coordinator = XBee24ZBCoordinator('/dev/ttyS1', 115200,
    "\x00\x13\xA2\x00\x40\x53\x56\x23", 'coord')
spalnya = XBee24ZBRemote('\x00\x13\xA2\x00\x40\x54\x1D\x12', 'spalnya')
spalnya.connectToCoordinator(coordinator)
vannaya = XBee24ZBRemote('\x00\x13\xA2\x00\x40\x54\x1D\x17', 'vannaya')    
vannaya.connectToCoordinator(coordinator)
led = LED()
led.connectTo(spalnya.getPin('DO4'), 'DO')
led.on()
led.off()
```

I, however, don't want to do that in code. I want to have an ini file that will define the topology of this 'network'. Thus I want this file to be readable and editable by a human. Logical choise is ini (against e.j. json as json when it comes to manual editing of config files is not super friendly to at least me).
Now, I got:

```
[xbee-coordinator]
type = XBee24ZBCoordinator
name = coord
comport = COM4
comspeed = 115200
```

I can create a function BuildNetwork('my.ini'), that will read and create the required object instances and connections between them. How do I do it? There's a class XBee24ZBCoordinator, but whar I get from ini is just a string...

Comment: could you use python for your config file syntax?  Thats probably the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

- Define all these classes in a module. Modules are just objects, so you can use `getattr()` on them:

  ```
  import types

  instance = getattr(types, typename)(arguments)
  ```
- Store them all in a dictionary and look them up by name; you don't have to type out the name in a string, the class has a `__name__` attribute you can re-use:

  ```
  types = {}

  class XBee24ZBCoordinator():
      # class definition

  types[XBee24ZBCoordinator.__name__] = XBee24ZBCoordinator
  ```

If these are defined in the 'current' module, the `globals()` function returns a dictionary too, so `globals()['XBee24ZBCoordinator']` is a reference to the class definition as well.